# .htaccess not working on drupal 7 when uploaded to pantheon server

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7, pantheon

My drupal site has a `.htaccess` file on which I am `redirecting` the page without changing the `URL`, Its working fine on `local server` & other `servers` but when I upload the files & databases to `pantheon server` It will not redirect the page saying `404 not found`. I placed `.htaccess` at the root of `code` folder, I tried placing it in `server root` folder, `sites` folder & `themes` folder but nothing works for me. Can any body know what is the correct placement of `.htaccess` in `drupal` site on `pantheon`? & why my `.htaccess` not working on `pantheon`?

Comment: check your server rewrite mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Pantheon servers use Nginx, and they don't enable .htaccess support.

You should contact them directly to discuss your options.

You can, however, perform redirects using Drupal’s settings.php, please see:

https://pantheon.io/docs/articles/sites/code/redirect-incoming-requests/

Answer (score 2):

Pantheon runs nginx, which ignores .htaccess files.

Answer (score 0):

Technically running Nginx with varnish.
[redirects](https://pantheon.io/docs/redirects/)
&
[redirect incoming requests](https://pantheon.io/docs/articles/sites/code/redirect-incoming-requests/)

```
// 301 Redirect from /old to /new.
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/old') &&
  (php_sapi_name() != "cli")) {
  header('HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently');
  header('Location: /new');
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this solution a little more?

Comment: Hi @TimS. Pantheon uses Fastly for redirects is the new CDN / redirect is done on the edge so 301's on Pantheon are unique [pantheon redirects] (https://pantheon.io/docs/guides/launch/redirects/) because the server does not use Apache at all, therefore, can not utilize **Apache HTaccess** So to replace Apache they use Nginx, Varnish & an All Varnish CDN called Fastly they ask you to use look at this [htaccess Alternative] (https://pantheon.io/docs/htaccess/)  I hope that helps, Tom

Answer (score 0):

**Pantheon does not use htaccess files** found because it does not use  Apache. Pantheon uses Varnish and Nginx combined with the fastly CDN is now standard on all updated HTTPS installs.

***"Redirects should be managed in PHP, since .htaccess is ignored. For details, see Using PHP as an htaccess Alternative."***
https://pantheon.io/docs/htaccess/

Configure redirects to the primary domain with HTTPS in settings.php

The redirect set up for Pantheon is extremely unique. It is able to allow PHP redirects to go straight to the varnish layer without the traditional latency of PHP redirects.

**For Drupal 7 Add the following to the end of your settings.php file (replace www.example.com):**

```
if (isset($_SERVER['PANTHEON_ENVIRONMENT']) && php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
  // Redirect to https://$primary_domain in the Live environment
  if ($_ENV['PANTHEON_ENVIRONMENT'] === 'live') {
    /** Replace www.example.com with your registered domain name */
    $primary_domain = 'www.example.com';
  }
  else {
    // Redirect to HTTPS on every Pantheon environment.
    $primary_domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  }

  if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != $primary_domain
      || !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_SSL'])
      || $_SERVER['HTTP_X_SSL'] != 'ON' ) {

    # Name transaction "redirect" in New Relic for improved reporting (optional)
    if (extension_loaded('newrelic')) {
      newrelic_name_transaction("redirect");
    }

    header('HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: https://'. $primary_domain . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit();
  }
}
```

See
https://pantheon.io/docs/guides/launch/redirects/

https://pantheon.io/docs/domains/

For HTTPS
https://pantheon.io/docs/http-to-https/

**Redirect to Subdirectories or Specific URLs**

*To redirect from a subdomain to a specific area of the site, use the following:*

```
// Redirect subdomain to a specific path.
if (isset($_SERVER['PANTHEON_ENVIRONMENT']) &&
  ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'subdomain.yoursite.com') &&
  // Check if Drupal or WordPress is running via command line
  (php_sapi_name() != "cli")) {
  $newurl = 'http://www.yoursite.com/subdomain/'. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  header('HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently');
  header("Location: $newurl");
  exit();
}
```

***For Drupal 8 (thought this may be helpful too as Drupal 8 & Drupal 7 have slightly different redirect set ups)* 
Add the following to the end of your settings.php file (replace www.example.com):**

```
if (isset($_SERVER['PANTHEON_ENVIRONMENT']) && php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
  // Redirect to https://$primary_domain in the Live environment
  if ($_ENV['PANTHEON_ENVIRONMENT'] === 'live') {
    /** Replace www.example.com with your registered domain name */
    $primary_domain = 'www.example.com';
  }
  else {
    // Redirect to HTTPS on every Pantheon environment.
    $primary_domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  }

  if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != $primary_domain
      || !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_SSL'])
      || $_SERVER['HTTP_X_SSL'] != 'ON' ) {

    # Name transaction "redirect" in New Relic for improved reporting (optional)
    if (extension_loaded('newrelic')) {
      newrelic_name_transaction("redirect");
    }

    header('HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: https://'. $primary_domain . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit();
  }
  // Drupal 8 Trusted Host Settings
  if (is_array($settings)) {
    $settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array('^'. preg_quote($primary_domain) .'$');
  }
}
```